# downloading data Json pictures

Tags: iphone, xcode

hi this is a part of my code

```
NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://*****.php"];

NSString *donneeJson = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL];

self.pseudoOnline = [donneeJson JSONValue];

NSDictionary *json2 = [pseudoOnline valueForKey: @"photo"];

NSLog(@"adresse photo%@",[pseudoOnline valueForKey: @"photo"]);

NSString *url = [[pseudoOnline valueForKey: @"photo"]objectAtIndex:0];  

NSLog(@"adresse photo%@",url    );

adresse photo(
    "http://************/XWsmG18O27.jpg",
    "http://************/Wz0ab6oIxU.jpg",
    "http://***********/9yKzQrpO59.jpg",
    "http://************/l2rbNeIK8a.jpg")


UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
```

how i can download all the pictures because iam only take picture index0 !

thks

thks

Comment: An `NSArray` isn't a dictionary.  You can't reference an element by a key.  You'll need to use an index.

Answer (score 0):

ads2 is an instance of NSArray, not NSDictionary. NSArray is not a key-value collection and does not respond to valueForKey:

Comment: i need to download all the pictures in the same time